# Code doesnt work with "createElement" but works if element previously created

Tags: javascript

It doesnt show anything on the browser if I use createElement, but if I previusly add an empty `<ul>` in the HTML and use the code in the comments it works.

```js
let ul = document.createElement('ul'); //If instead of this

/*let ul = document.querySelector('ul');*/ //Use this, it works

let fragmento = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerText = "item " + i;
    fragmento.appendChild(li)
}

ul.appendChild(fragmento);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!--<ul></ul>-->
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just append your `<ul>` to the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`let ul = document.createElement('ul');` creates the element but it's not attached to the document.  You try to do that with `ul.appendChild(fragmento);`, but as you found, that only works if the element is already in the document.  Use another element like `body` with: `document.querySelector('body').appendChild(fragmento);`.